# Do I need a credit card on file to get free apps?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ios-appstore

I am going to preface this by saying I don't think it is duplicate because the other questions are older and ever so slightly different.The only question that really might be a duplicate was asked three years ago and based on someone who is in Argentina.

Do I need to provide a credit card number to get a free app in the United States? I am asking because I want to buy and iPod touch and do not have a credit card!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set your payment details to **none** when you set up your Apple ID. This way you can download free content without the use of a creditcard.

Comment: Okay, and this feature is available in the US?

Comment: @L.B. Yes it is.

Comment: I can't find "none" in the options

Comment: @Komi It appeared the first time I accessed the app store through my iPod Touch. A screen comes up and asks for your address and stuff, at the top of that screen, it asks about payment options. If you have the ability to choose "None" it should be where Apple asks about payment/credit card information at the very top of the list of options.

Answer (score 3):

download a free app first, then when prompted, create a new account.  Because this app is free you do not need to put in CC info.

Answer (score 1):

the none feature itself is only available when making in on a portable i device such as an iPod or iPad when going in through the iTunes app before creating your account.

Answer (score 1):

[HERE](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204034) is Apple's page on this.

In particular: create a new Apple ID without a credit card or other payment method.

also: [remove](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1918) the payment method from an already existing Apple ID.

and: [what to do](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203905) if "none" isn't showing, or you can't select it.