# Payment verification

Tags: itunes-store

When I go to download free apps it says it wants a payment method. I have already changed my settings to "none" like everyone says to do. But it still asks for one. How do I get it to stop asking for this after I already changed everything?

Answer (score 3):

You only get to choose none when you set up a new account. If it wants verification, you will need to enter payment or contact support and have them somehow waive that on the back end.

See:

- [Can I download a free app from the App Store without a credit card?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10180/)
- [Do I need a credit card on file to get free apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131173/)

Now - once you've added a card and verified, you might be able to go back to none, but your account was somehow flagged as needing verification so Apple Support would need to weigh in if that was intentional or can be waived.

Answer (score 3):

You may have an outstanding charge made to your account. Call Apple Support (1-800-MY-APPLE) and ask to speak with iTunes Support. They'll be able to take a look at your account.

Comment: Useful - but we don't all live in the US. International numbers available through https://support.apple.com/contact

Comment: Understood, which is why one should specify their region when an answer like this is posted. That'll way they can be properly assisted.